What is the format/template used by Nature Reviews Journal Paper
I am trying to find the latex template used by the following article: https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-023-06221-2
I have tried the Nature Journal template provided by https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support#c17590862
However, the official template only supports a single column and is not the same as the desired one. I tried to google the problem in this How to get Springer two column latex template. The official latex template contains not svjour3 in it.
Hence, I tried to use the svjour3 template directly but it is different from Nature Reviews.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I do not think the article you link to at the top is done with TeX, but maybe that is not relevant.

I think it would be best to contact "nature". After all, they'll have a lot of data processing behind, e.g. to provide the content as website, pdf etc. // However, you can always start writing with a standard class, and introduce visual changes, like layouts, fonts etc., step by step using appropriate packages.
